# How to put multiple arguments inside OPTION for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, select

I created a table in SQL via PHP that has 3 columns. I'm trying to put the values inside a SELECT dropdown in this way:

- The first column will be in the value of the OPTION (for passing in the POST).
- The second column will be in the display of the OPTION.
- The third column will be hidden and sticks to each row in the dropdown, so when the user chooses one option from the dropdown, the hidden column will present in other div.

For example, if the table is:

```
col1  col2  col3
-----------------
1     Joe   Key st.
2     Matt  Link st.
```

When the user chooses Joe, `Key st.` will display in a separate div, and after the user presses enter, the value `1` will be sent via POST.

This is what I got so far:

```js
$('.foo3').on('change', function() {
  var add = $(this).parent().find('.foo3').value();
  $('.foo2').html(add);
});
```

```html
<select class="foo3">
  <?php while ($curRow=mysqli_fetch_array($TableOutput)) {                                                      
    echo "<input class='foo' type='hidden' value='{$curRow['col3']}'><option value='{$curRow['col1']}'>{$curRow['col2']}</option>"; 
  } ?>
</select>
<div class="foo2"></div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please attach your HTML output?

Comment: It doesn't work. the dropdown was empty.

Comment: @RuchishParikh Why did you edit the HTML of my answer in to this question?

Comment: I have edited to convert it into code snippet. sorry if I am wrong. @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: It's fine to edit the question to include a snippet, but the problem was you used the HTML from my answer, not the OPs original code. Please take care in future.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan he is converting question to answer and vice versa :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store your own metadata in an element by using `data` attribute. You can then read that back out when the `option` is chosen. Try this:

```js
$('.foo3').change(function() {
  $('.foo2').text($(this).find('option:selected').data('location'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="foo3">
  <option>Please select...</option>
  <option value="1" data-location="Key St.">Joe</option>
  <option value="2" data-location="Link St.">Matt</option>
</select>
<div class="foo2"></div>
```

To create that HTML output, your PHP would look like this:

```
echo "<option value=\"{$curRow['col1']}\" data-location=\"{$curRow['col3']}\">{$curRow['col2']}</option>";
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan is it good to store data in html element ? will it cause slow to load ??

Comment: It's absolutely fine, and it won't affect performance in any noticable way.

Comment: There is no real difference between having the data show on the page, and load it into a `data`-attribute. There is a very slight overhang (perhaps) of HTML-code, but it should be (in most cases) minimal, and not provide any difference in loading time.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie there's also the overhead of jQuery building the cache object, but again the delay is infinitesimal. If performance is of that high a concern you shouldn't be using jQuery at all.

Comment: That is true, but that wasn't really what he was asking. As for the pure HTML, of which you can also use data-tags for other purposes, there isn't really that much overhead (at least not until you get into thousands up thousands of tags, which you never should have anyway).

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - There is a solution for more than two PHP values...? I just realized I need more than one extra...

Comment: @DvirNaim the same technique works, just add another `data-XXX` attribute and use `data('XXX')` to retrieve it in jQuery

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - Perfect again. You're an angel programmer !